# Bukkit MySQL syntax error

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm getting the following syntax error

Here's sql table structure
http://puu.sh/jqPcK/f53bac000a.png

```
[18:48:42 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in = 0, Unbanned by = 'Crypted', Banned on = 'Ban Removed', Reason = 'dog unb ',' at line 1
```

Here's PART of my code

```
                 PreparedStatement revoke = sql.c.prepareStatement("UPDATE `bans` SET Name = ?, Expires in = ?, Unbanned by = ?, Banned on = ?, Reason = ?, Banned = ? WHERE UUID = ? ");

                 if ( args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("revoke") )
                 {

                     revoke.setString(1, off.getName());
                     revoke.setInt(2, 0);
                     revoke.setString(3, sender.getName());
                     revoke.setString(4, "Ban Removed");
                     revoke.setString(5, message);
                     revoke.setInt(6, 0);
                     revoke.setString(7, off.getUniqueId().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expires in` is being read as two tokens. Usually your database fields would be named as such: expires_in so that this issue doesn't occur. In future dont use spaces in field names.

In this case, you can change your statement and surround the names with backticks to denote that they are a single token.

`` UPDATE `bans` SET Name = ?, `Expires in` = ?, `Unbanned by` = ?, `Banned on` = ?, Reason = ?, Banned = ? WHERE UUID = ? ``